# How to Generalize $\left(1+e^{ix}\right)^n+\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)^n$ for any $x$ value?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

The following formula is true for any $n\in \mathbb{R}$  and  $x \in \left[-\pi ,\pi \right]$
$$\left(1+e^{ix}\right)^n+\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)^n=2^{n+1}\cos ^n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)$$
My question is how to generalize above RHS's formula for any $x$?

Comment: (I suppose your "$R$" is $\Bbb N$?) Take the time to prove this formula and you'll see it is valid for "any" $x$ (even complex).

Comment: @AnneBauval R is in Real Number not just integer

Comment: Then may be you should edit your post to define the powers of the LHS.

Comment: Looks generalised already to me? Both sides are periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: You need more restrictions on $n$.  The LHS is periodic, but the right-hand side requires at least $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ to be periodic, possibly $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to avoid branch issues...

Comment: $\cos(nx/2)$ is not periodic with period $2\pi$ if $n$ is not an integer. @preferred_anon